# how to convert list into readable format

Tags: java, hibernate, list, spring-mvc, collections

When I execute this code, I get the solution. I need to convert the list into readable format. My Dao code is

```
    public List<Data> getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("In getData dao************");
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx=session.beginTransaction();
    List<Data> blist=session.createCriteria(>.class).list();
    System.out.println("datalist dao************"+blist);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return blist;
}
```

Data.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_genere")
public class Data implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="dataid")
private String DataId;

@Column(name="dataname")
private String DataName;

public String getDataId() {
    return DataId;
}

public void setDataId(String dataId) {
    DataId = dataId;
}

public String getDataName() {
    return DataName;
}

public void setDataName(String dataName) {
    DataName = dataName;
}
```

}

I get the solution, but it's in unreadable format. How can I convert it to readable format? The answer is dao************[com.pack.web.model.Data@1233c96, com.pack.web.model.Data@5ec471]. But I need to store the list into a file as json format. How can I do this.

Comment: override method toString() in class Data

Comment: iterate `blist` and print that. You are printing `blist<Data>` object. or override the toString() in Data.

Comment: @Rahul Please explain with my example.

Comment: @ema could you plz explain with my example..

Comment: @PriyankaShaju code change is posted in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override toString() of an object. Use as below or change it according to your requirement.

```
   @Entity
        @Table(name="tbl_genere")
        public class Data implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="dataid")
        private String DataId;

        @Column(name="dataname")
        private String DataName;

        public String getDataId() {
            return DataId;
        }

        public void setDataId(String dataId) {
            DataId = dataId;
        }

        public String getDataName() {
            return DataName;
        }

        public void setDataName(String dataName) {
            DataName = dataName;
        }

        public String toString(){
        return DataId+","+DataName;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override `toString()` in your `Data` class

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "DataId='" + DataId + '\'' +
                ", DataName='" + DataName + '\'' +
                '}';
      }
```

and then in your `getData()` method.

```
 for(int i=0;i<blist.size();i++){
            System.out.println(blist.toString());  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The List is taking the Data as generic. Override tostring() method in Data class and in Sysout use Arrays.toString(blist.toArray()); You w'll get the answer in readable format.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct `JSON` format output in `toString` method as shown below:

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
     StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
     builder.append("{Data : {DataId:\'").append(DataId).append("\' , DataName: \'")
        .append(DataName).append("\' } }");
     builder.toString();
    }
```

Note: Make sure you have escaped single/double quotes to get proper `json` output.